# Inner join on two columns that their values are not 100% equal

Tags: excel, ssis, inner-join

I've two excel files, one with two columns (ID1, Name) and the other with two columns (ID2, Name) and I need to export one file with three columns (ID1, ID2, Name).

And the problem is there are names in each of the files that are not in the other, and the bigger problem is that there are some differences in writing the same name in the two files which are common differences in the language of the files, like the character 'أ' in Arabic could be wrote without the Hamza 'ا' (I mean I can't use the standard equal operation between two strings to specify that the name in one file is the same as another with the other file).

And my question is there any tools that could help without going into writing a code for it, I've heard about SQL Integration Services but I don't know anything about it, could you please point me to any references that could help with solving my problem.

Any link, suggestion, or other help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You have an interesting problem but unfortunately in this situation interesting = hard. With English type names, we could employ a number of name matching algorithms (Double Metaphone, Minimum Edit Distance, Damerau–Levenshtein distance, etc) but I don't know how well those will work with a rich language like Arabic. I answered a somewhat similar question over on SU 
https://superuser.com/questions/480133/record-matching-software-to-compare-two-tables-and-match-on-based/481592

It won't hurt to try the Fuzzy capabilities of SSIS: [Fuzzy Lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137786.aspx) and [Fuzzy Grouping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137786.aspx). In your case, fuzzy grouping is what you'll want to experiment with. These are Enterprise Edition features so be aware of that from a licensing perspective. They will work fine in your Development Edition but if you deploy and try to run on a Standard Edition of SQL Server, it'll fail.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and your detailed answer you pointed to, I'll leave this question unanswered for a while to get some other answers.